# Cosets of symmetric groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

What is an element from each left coset of s6 in s7?

I don't completely understand cosets in symmetric groups.

Comment: For which groups do you understand cosets?

Comment: Let $H=S_6$.  A left coset is an element $gH$, where $g\in S_7$.

Comment: Multiplicative and additive of Z. I know if g is in G then gH equals the set of gH | h in H contained in G

Answer (score 2):

Lets work with smaller symmetric groups.  Let's let $G=S_3$, $H=S_2$.  We can actually write out each group in set notation;

$$S_3=\{(1), (12), (13), (23), (123), (132)\}$$

$$S_2=\{(1), (12)\}$$

Now, for any $g\in S_3$, a left coset is a set $gH$.  What does that mean?  Well, lets look at $g=(23)$.  We can "multiply" all elements in $S_2$ by $(23)$.  Of course, when working with the symmetric group, we are composing, not multiplying, but you get the idea i hope.  Then

$$(23)H=(23) \{(1),(12)\}=\{(23)(1), (23)(12)\}=\{(23),(132)\}$$

This is one of the left cosets of $H=S_2$ in $S_3$.  The same principle can be applied to your problem, but of course there are a lot more elements in $S_6$ and $S_7$, so now using @C Monsour's answer should help to enlighten a bit more...

Answer (score 0):

The way to think of cosets is as a set that the group acts transitively on, with the subgroup as a point stabilizer.  If you think about it, S6 inside S7 stabilizes a point in the natural action on 7 letters.  If you choose S6 to stabilize 1 (i.e., it only acts on the numbers 2 through 7) then the right cosets correspond to the sets of all elements mapping 1 to 1, mapping 1 to 2, ..., mapping 1 to 7, and the left cosets correspond to the sets of all elements mapping 1 to 1, 2 to 1, ..., 7 to 1.

Comment: I think I understand this but could you write it out?

Comment: @Hopper Write what out? Write out one element from each coset? If you understand this answer, you should be able to do that, right now.